# Gensim Doc2vec – KeyError: "tag not seen in training corpus/invalid"

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I am using gensim's Doc2vec to learn features from news articles. I can successfully train my documents. However, I struggle to retrieve the document vectors from the model for further processing.

Example code (directly taken [from gensim's documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#usage-examples)):

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts

documents = [TaggedDocument((doc), [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(common_texts)]
model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)
```

This correctly trains without error.

If I try to use `model.docvecs` directly or iterate over it like so:

```
for vector in model.docvecs:
    print(vector)
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError: "tag '9' not seen in training corpus/invalid"
```

What is the reason for this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it...

I need to use

`model.docvecs.doctag_syn0` *(soon to be deprecated)*

or

`model.docvecs.vectors_docs`